# How to Delete Distribution Profile convert to Standard

Tags: 8, distributions

We are using OpenSocial distro and because our direction has changed we no longer need to use distribution. Therefore we need to go back to the standard installation.

Is it possible to move all the modules and remove the OpenSocial profile and basically convert the site to standard installation? The site is managed with the composer.

Comment: D8 to D8 migration is a safe bet.